# SQL Server error with query

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to generate a report from data stored in my database but i'm having an error

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'Production.ProductCategory.Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

My query is the following

```
SELECT
    pc.Name AS Categoria,
    DATEPART(YEAR, soh.OrderDate) AS [ano],
    SUM((det.UnitPrice - det.UnitPriceDiscount) * det.OrderQty) AS total,
    SUM(soh.Freight) AS transporte,
    SUM(det.LineTotal) AS vendas
FROM
    Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS soh
INNER JOIN
    Sales.SalesPerson AS sp ON sp.BusinessEntityID = soh.SalesPersonID
INNER JOIN
    Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS det ON soh.SalesOrderID = det.SalesOrderID
INNER JOIN
    HumanResources.Employee AS e ON soh.SalesPersonID = e.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN
    Person.Person AS per ON per.BusinessEntityID = sp.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN
    Production.Product AS p ON det.ProductID = p.ProductID
INNER JOIN 
    Production.ProductSubcategory AS ps ON p.ProductSubcategoryID = ps.ProductSubcategoryID
INNER JOIN
    Production.ProductCategory AS pc ON ps.ProductCategoryID = pc.ProductCategoryID
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(YEAR, soh.OrderDate)
ORDER BY
    DATEPART(YEAR, soh.OrderDate);
```

I want to have just one accessories/clothes/bicycle, etc and one time 2011/2012 etc...

Comment: just add pc.Name to the group by

Comment: Don't be scared to format your queries so they don't look like a wall of text.

Answer (score 3):

change this line:

```
group by DATEPART(YEAR, soh.OrderDate)
```

to this

```
group by DATEPART(YEAR, soh.OrderDate), pc.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

add

```
GROUP BY pc.Name
```

to the bottom of your query